# Saving file to multi dimensional table

Tags: java, file, multidimensional-array

I have function that takes as parameter: `Object[][]`
I have a file with objects such as:

```
"some string"|12|"Another text"|34567
"sstring"|899|"text"|23425
"soing"|11|"Anext"|234
"somng"|11|"Ano text"|23
```

I do not know how to pass this values to function. Number of rows and columns might be different in each file.

Comment: Technically, file will not have objects, it will have text/string. You will need to read the file and create the String objects or array as needed so that it makes sense ..

Comment: `Number of rows and columns might be different in each file.` - which is why you should not use an Array because you don't know how big to create the Array. Instead you should use an ArrayList. An ArrayList is dynamic so you can add as many items to the List as you need.

Comment: And how to convert an array of arrays to two dimentional table?

@hagrawal Technically it will have only strings, but the issue is not what type it will be.

Comment: Think of "table" as logical concept, 2D array is the technical representation of that logical concept of table .. `00, 01, 02 ... 10, 11, 12 ... 20, 21, 22 ...` .. It all depends on how you want to process the things, I see in your data you have words and numbers as well .. In any case, since you said that you have `Object[][]` as function parameter, so you need to make a 2D array and pass the same to your function ..

Comment: Lets leave processing the data from table. I do not know how to nicely initialize this table with data from file. If it easies problem, it might be all int values.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like the below - (not complete code but I think you will get the idea)-

```
Object[][] myObject = new Object[][]();
int rowIndex = 0;
while(<your file has lines>) {
   String line = <read one line from your file>;
   String[] elements = line.split("|");
   myObject[rowIndex++] = elements;
}
```

Comment: Any element of myObject[i] is an array of Objects itself. It might be possible to not use two dimensional arrays as all these are of type Object. But from what I understand -  the required data structure is a 2D array of Objects and not any arbitrary structure.

Comment: @hagrawal And what is a difference between 2D array and array of arrays?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Jesus Christ !!!  Are you serious or am I sincere ?? I wish there was a down vote button in the comment and I would have used it, anyways retracted that. :)

Comment: @hagrawal This is a very useful explanation, I am glad you were able to answer the question I have asked. By the way, why is your original comment removed?

Comment: @hagrawal That's very interesting that you cannot point out any existing sources supporting your claim that 2D array and array of arrays are somehow different in Java - or whatever the criticism in your original comment was about.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Dear Jaroslaw, I voted up your comment because it made sense, you were right and I accepted that. However, there is no point of chewing this gum any further.

Comment: @hagrawal I am really just interested in the difference.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak How about galvanization messing up the due diligence .. :)

Comment: 'Object[][] myObject = new Object[][]();'

Cannot do that, so this approach is unfortunately wrong.

Comment: Object[][] myObject = new Object[10][10];
This will create a 10 x 10 array. Of course you might not know in advance that a 10 x 10 array will be sufficient - but that is the downside of using arrays. You can consider using List's instead.